# Excel sheet merged cell reading using apache poi in java

Tags: java, excel, apache

I am reading the excel sheet using Apache poi in java and I am using `CellRangeAddress` to get the region.

Case1: If I  am giving 2-3 data for merging and going for next cell then it's ok.
I'm getting the next merged region .

Case2: If I am giving more than 6 values and going for next region, then It is showing `IndexOutofBoundException` for merged region

Here The Code:

```
List<OrganizationDB> orgList = new ArrayList<OrganizationDB>();
List<EmployeeDB> empList;
XSSFWorkbook workBook;
XSSFSheet excelSheet;
XSSFRow row;
XSSFCell cells;
TreeViewer treeViewer = null;


File excelFile = new File("D:\\ExcelExport\\ExcelSheet2.xls");
FileInputStream fis;

if (excelFile.exists()) {
    fis = new FileInputStream(excelFile);

    workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    excelSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);

    int count  = 1;     

    while (count <= excelSheet.getLastRowNum()) {               

        CellRangeAddress region = excelSheet.getMergedRegion(count);
        row = excelSheet.getRow(count);
        //XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);

        orgDb = new OrganizationDB();

        orgDb.setOrganizationName(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
        orgDb.setCityName(row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
        orgDb.setStateName(row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue());

        empList = new ArrayList<EmployeeDB>();

        while(count<=region.getLastRow()) {

            row = excelSheet.getRow(count);
            empDb = new EmployeeDB();

            empDb.setCompanyName(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
            empDb.setEmpID(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
            empDb.setEmpName(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
            empDb.setPhoneNo((int) row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue());
            empList.add(empDb);
            orgDb.setEmpList(empList);
            count++;
        }
        orgList.add(orgDb);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a logic in your code, which I do not fully understand. Could you check it please?
You have one counter `count` used by two nested while loops.

```
while (count <= excelSheet.getLastRowNum()) {
            CellRangeAddress region      = excelSheet.getMergedRegion(count);
...
    while(count<=region.getLastRow()){
...
        count++;
```

perhaps there are two merged regions with rows 1 to 3 and 4 to 6, then after first run of your top `while` your count = 3, because nested `while` increased it.
Then code tries to get mergedRegion(3) and
there is no mergedRegion with the index 3.
It must be mergedRegion(2) with next set of rows instead...

I guess you have to use different counters for mergedRegions and rows in them.